# C++ Project uses Sqlite database how to ship or deploy?

Tags: c++, deployment, sqlite

Currently my project in c++ uses a sqlite database (.db) for storing information which is used for computation how do I ship my DLL and .db file so application that is meant to use it can get together. Currently I am just zip them and have batch file saying how to use it. Is there any better way to share my C++ DLL and few more dependent dll and Sqlite db with client?

Comment: Given you're using C++, just compile sqlite3.c directly in your program instead of messing with a dll version.

Answer (score 0):

There are a range of options for deploying your solution on Windows

1. [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) works well with powershell
2. If the customer is in-house use a Repo manager, i.e. just drop the zip file there.
3. Nullsoft Scriptable Install System ([NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page)) lets you create an installer.
4. [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) also works with C++ projects.

Apart from that you also need to think about release notes, versions, logging, support notification etc. etc. to make it easier to support.

You can also study devops if you want to become an export in this field!